# How to login as a user to Google Cloud Workstations

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-iam, google-cloud-iam, google-cloud-workstations

I'm trying to figure out whether it's possible to login as a given user to a Google Cloud Workstation. Currently, when I create a Cloud Workstation, the logged in user is "user".

For context, when setting up a standalone (not a Cloud Workstation) Google Cloud VM, I can enable OSLogin, which maps my user in IAM into the Linux environment.

I want a user to be able to login to a Cloud Workstation with their given user IAM permissions. Is this possible in Cloud Workstations? I know within the Workstation Configuration (under Advanced Container options), you can run as a given UID, although not sure whether I can use that for the above usecase.